# Floating action button in Android on all the screens

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, touch-event

I am a newbie is android , As a part of my project, I need to  create a floating action button  which is seen all screen all overs the device ,and on click of that button should disable the screen touch sensitivity of the screen and one more click on the FAB buttons will enable the screen touch sensitivity.

Can anybody please help to achieve this.

Is there any library I can make use of ?
Complete explanation to achieve this.

Comment: Do you really mean "all over the device", or just your own app? Because if it's the former, I don't expect that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

check out `AccessibilityService`, using it you can lock and unlock (control) touch on whole device (besides when locked). probably you can use it also for showing additional button "above everything", if not you may interest in `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission which allows that

Comment: can't edit answer (weird, some bug on SO...?), so links to doc here:  [`AccessibilityService`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service) and [`SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-draw-over-other-apps-in-android/)